# How to check localhost website to android phone

Tags: android, asp.net, sql-server, localhost

I need to check my website on my android phone , i wonder how can i connect it through `localhost`. need help please.

I'm using SQL Server as database engine.

Answer (score 1):

If it's connected to your wifi, then hit your laptop address provided by the router. If it's connected to your mobile network, then first find out your router external IP address, then forward some port to that 10.0.2.2:portno and finally you'll be able to see that server from your device.